# submit button in login form is not working for my asp net MVC based signup and login application.signup working but have some problem with login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my login action. The submit button in the login form is not working. The signup action successfully stores data in the database but I am having a problem with the login action. I am fetching data in the login action but I think it does not work. I don't know a reason.

----Models-----

```
 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Confirmpassword { get; set; }
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }

    }
```

--dbcontext----

```
namespace MVC_Boostrap.Models
{
    public class Projectdatacontext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { set; get; }
    }
}
```

------controller------

```
        public ActionResult Login( User user)
        {
            User u = p1.Users.FirstOrDefault(Users => Users.Email == user.Email && Users.Password == Users.Password);
            if (u != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Login";
                return View();

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Enter Correct Email and Password";
                return View();
            }
            //return RedirectToAction("Welcome", u);
        }
```

---SignUp action-------------

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Signup( User user)
        {
            try
            {
                p1.Users.Add(user);
                p1.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Signup Succesfully";
                //return RedirectToAction("Welcome", user);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Signup error:" + ex.ToString();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

-------------login view-------------------------

```
@model MVC_Boostrap.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Login Form</h4>
                        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
                        {
                            <div class="alert alert-primary">@ViewBag.Message</div>
                        }
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Email ID:")
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, new { @Placeholder = "Please Enter Email-ID", @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Password :")
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Password, new { @Placeholder = "Please enter your Passoword", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>  //this button does not perform anythng
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        New Users Signup <a href="#">Here</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

No error message in the browser console and visual studio.

Comment: Go check out the answer from Izzy, it's a good answer. I just want to say something about the Password you're storing. Is that clear text? In other words, if you query the database, can you read that person's password?

If so, you really should change that as it is a big security problem. Read more about it here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d0e913/how-will-you-store-a-password-in-database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem on the login view is that your input elements are not inside any `<form>` element so therefore when you click on the submit button the browser really does not know where to send that data so it just returns you to the same screen by hitting the `HttpGet` action of Login. To fix this problem simply do

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login","ControllerName")){ //code inside here }
```

Now moving onto your controller where you also have a problem which is your Login action isn't decorated with `HttpPost` attribute so when the submit button is clicked the default `HttpGet` Login action will be hit. Just a small change similar to that of your Signup action you have to do

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user) { //code inside here }
```

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776598/3793448)** answer explains what happens when you decorate your action with `HttpPost` attribute.